# I need help understanding a programming challenge

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, polymorphism

I am trying to do some homework and cannot wrap my head around a question. I have posted in the classes discussion board and emailed the professor but am not getting any help.

The question is:
Design a class *abstractSort* that can be used to analyze the number of comparisons performed by a sorting algorithm. The class should have a member function compare that is capable of comparing two array elements, and a means of keeping track of the number of comparisons performed. The class should be an abstract class with a pure virtual member function

```
virtual void Sort(int arr[], int size)= 0;
```

which, when overridden, will sort the array by calling the compare function **to determine with the relative order of pairs of numbers** (that is the phrase I don't get). Create a subclass of AbstractSort that uses a simple sorting algorithm to implement the sort function. The class should have a member function that can be called after the sorting is done to determine the number of comparisons performed.

I have an idea of how to code this but I just don't think that I am going about it the way the question is worded. I have written code to keep track of comparisons by incrementing a counter and outputting that number. The question is bugging me however. What does the author mean by saying "by calling the compare function **to determine with the relative order of pairs of numbers** "

Does anybody have any idea of what they mean? am I just over complicating an obvious question or is there some subtle challenge to this that I don't see. 
As I stated I do not need help coding the problem, just understanding the question.

Comment: Whenever you need to figure out the relative order of pairs of numbers ("is n1 greater than, less than or equal to n2?") you will call the compare function.

Comment: So instead of calling bubble or quicksort to sort the array I will use compare?

Comment: If you are going to ask about your homework, please [read how to ask](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/226653)

Comment: @Mgetz I think this question was pretty well articulated compared to the usual homework questions. The OP has shown some effort, and is even showing the exact phrasing they do not understand...

Comment: @Segmented it is, that said it still needs to **show us what they've tried** or that they've **researched solutions**

Comment: @Mgetz I have read that post and I believe that I have followed it. I am asking for help in comprehending a problem that I have been assigned. I have stated that I have coded a solution that works but I am not sure if it meets the requirements of the assignment. I have asked for clarification on the question to make sure that I am writing the correct code for the problem. If this were work I would be in the business analysts office asking for requirement clarifications.

Comment: @Guyute unfortunately the only person who can definitively clarify would be your professor, but nevertheless I think asking for clarification on the general concepts has a definite place here.

Comment: @Guyute in the future, questions that are about the concepts of programming are probably better off on http://programmers.stackexchange.com , this just seems a bit off topic to me

Comment: @mgetz noted, I sometimes struggle with which is the right arena for a question such as this. One where I know a work around, but want to really grok the question.

Comment: @Guyute on this question... so did I, it's almost too code related for programmers but too theoretical for SO

Comment: Looks a programming/design task rather than a challenge. In a programming language that does not allow a derived entity to completely redefine attributes ([BETA](http://cs.au.dk/~beta/), for one), it should be simple. With C++ & co, you can support (e.g., in an abstract class) something (like invocation counting), but you are entirely dependent on the cooperation of overriding classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At some point during an ordinary implementation of most sorting algorithms, you'd have something like this:

```
if (elements[i] < elements[j]) {
    // Do something
}
else {
    // Do something else
}
```

It is often convenient to "outsource" the job of comparing the elements to a separate function (I'm assuming for simplicity that the elements being sorted are integers):

```
protected:
bool isSmaller(int a, int b) {
    return a < b;
}

// Inside sorting function:
if (isSmaller(elements[i], elements[j])) { ... } else { ... }
```

Combined with inheritance, you could define `isSmaller()` in a base class, and for each sorting algorithm you'd like to implement (quick sort, merge sort, insertion sort...), you'd create a new subclass. However, each subclass should call `isSmaller()` rather than using `<` to determine which elements should come before which. Then, you can add your "count the number of comparisions" code (which, as you say, would consist of simply incrementing a counter) to `isSmaller()`.

(The point of the task is to make you realize that inheritance can free you from having to duplicate the counting code in every sorting algorithm implementation. Also, when using function pointers or function objects, the idea of "outsourcing" the comparison can also be used to make a "configurable" sorting class where the user of the class can decide how comparisons are to be performed, in order to e.g. sort numbers descendingly, or to sort a list of persons based on their names, etc.)

Comment: The point of the task is to make you realize that inheritance can free you from having to duplicate the counting code in every sorting algorithm implementation. Also, when using function pointers or function objects, the idea of "outsourcing" the comparison can also be used to make a "configurable" sorting class where the user of the class can decide how comparisons are to be performed, in order to e.g. sort numbers descendingly, or to sort a list of persons based on their names, etc.  This phrase brings it all into context thank you.